# Meaning of -e in if clause without any variable checks in Perl

Tags: perl

I have an existing **PERL** code in my system Which is following format.

I am not sure what is being compared in following If clause. Could you please help me to understand ?

```
if (-e "$array_line_loc[-1]/$array_loc[-1]")
        {
        $location = 1;
    print "Location : $location\n";
        }
```

Comment: `-e` check for file existence. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601027/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-e` checks if the file exists. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Answer (score 2):

That snippets checks if the file (or directory) `$array_line_loc[-1]/$array_loc[-1]` exists. If yes, then `$location` will be set and `Location : $location\n` will be printed.

With `-1` index passed to an array ref last element will be taken. A better way to write that snippet is the following one:

```
...
use File::Spec::Functions qw[ catfile ];
...
if (-e catfile($array_line_loc[-1], $array_loc[-1])) {
...
}
```