# Error when tried to open a excel file from Perl using IIS

Tags: excel, perl, iis, win32ole

I am running a perl script file from c# application using IIS, in that I want to open a already existing Excel file and I am opening it using the following line:

```
$ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;}) 
or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";//upto this working fine

$book = $ex->Workbooks->Open($fileName); //this line only giving error
```

Now I am getting the error in the open as follows:

> OLE exception from "Microsoft Office Excel":
>
> Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file
>   'C:\GWATS\Report\Nov-17-2014_10-06-36\GES-11n_IOT_10-06-37.xls'. There are
>   several possible reasons:
>
> • The file name or path does not exist.
>
> • The file is being used by another program.
>
> • The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open
>   workbook.
>
> Win32::OLE(0.1711) error 0x800a03ec
>   in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Open" at C:\GWATS\Lib\System\Report.pm line 611.

The file is surely present I verified that.

Also this script is working fine when I directly run that in cmd. What is the problem here, I think the problem is with IIS but I could find what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Does the user account which IIS is using to run your script have access to the file?

Comment: yes Tim I added DefaultAppPool to users and given full control to Report folder

Comment: If you run a "file exists" check from perl using that path does it succeed?

Comment: when run from cmd prompt it is running fine. It is opening the file and writing the contents without any error.

Comment: Even when run as the IIS user account?

Comment: In your script add something like `(-e $fileName) or die "No file!";` before launching Excel.  What happens when you run from IIS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601027/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-perl

Comment: Ya (-e $fileName) gives file exists

Comment: Sorry - I don't have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Windows Explorer

Depending on whether you installed a 32bit or 64bit version of office you will need to do one (or both) of the following:

32bit Office installation: Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile

64bit Office installation: Navigate to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile

Verify the folder "Desktop" exists (create it if it's not there)

Right click > Properties

On the security tab: Add the account under which the site is running (eg: DefaultAppPool) with default permissions (Read & execute; List folder contents; Read)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below perl script. If still some error exists let me know:

**Code:**

```
   use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
   use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel'; 

   my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
     || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
    my $filename = 'C:\GWATS\Report\Nov-17-2014_10-06-36\GES-11n_IOT_10-06-37.xls'
    my $book  = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($filename);
```

Comment: Can i know the error ? Is it the same or different ?

Answer (score 0):

i faced similar issue

it worked for me when i gave the **absolute path** for the files