# How to validate a plain text file in perl

Tags: perl

I have tried to use *`if`* statement with arguments like `-e`, `-f` and `-T` to check if a file exist, if it's a file and if it's a **plain text** file.

```
print "$_ is readable text\n" if -e $_ && $f $_ && -T $_;
```

But this won't work as expected: Some binary files is chown.

Comment: First define plain text, and how it differs from some other type of file.  Are you concerned with MIME types, with human readability? Is base64 plain text? Are Russian, Farsee, and Sanskrit plain text?  If not, what language should plain text be?

Comment: In addition to what @DavidO said, you really need to show us your code otherwise we won't be able to tell you if you're on the right track.

Comment: Post your current code...

Comment: I'm not familiar with programming language so, still learning the basics from knowing nothing about programming language, but anyway, here is my code:
<code>
`#! usr/bin/perl`
`use strict;`
`use warnings;`

`sub textfile_validate ($_) {`
` chomp;`
` open (my $FH, $_);`
` warn "$_ not exist, please try again\n" if (! -e $FH);`
` warn "$_ is an invalide text file, please try again" if (! -f $FH && ! -T $FH);`
` print "Text file validated successfully!\n"if ($FH);`
`}`

`print "insert name of the the first file: ";`
`my $first_file = <STDIN>;`
`textfile_validate($_= $first_file);`<code\>

Comment: -e -f etc work with file names not file handlers. You don't need to open a file to check its existence. Distinguishing text from non-text (binary) is more tricky

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a file exists in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601027/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-perl)

Comment: @serenesat this question is not about existing file, but about if content if plain ascii or not...

Comment: @Laurdora please **post your code** (What you already tried)!!

Comment: @F.Hauri: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2601042/4248931) state that _The code `print "$base_path exists!\n" if -e $base_path;` will generate output if a plain file exists at that path_.

Comment: @serenesat `plain file` is not `plain text file` (ie non binary file)

Answer (score 1):

### [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s *heuristic* test for determining if `-B` or `-T`

command `perldoc -f -T | sed -ne '/-T.*"-B".*work/,+3p'` output:

> ```
>           The "-T" and "-B" switches work as follows.  The first block or
>           so of the file is examined for odd characters such as strange
>           control codes or characters with the high bit set.  If too many
>           strange characters (>30%) are found, it's a "-B" file;
> ```

So if `30%` don't match your need, you have to use another way:

### Use [Test::PureASCII](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Test-PureASCII-0.02/lib/Test/PureASCII.pm)

```
  use Test::PureASCII tests => $how_many;
  file_is_pure_ascii($filename1, "only ASCII in $filaname1");
```

### or build your own test routine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -CIO
use strict;

sub testfile {
    open FH, "<" . $_[0];
    my $block = " " x 4096;
    sysread FH, $block, 4096;
    close FH;
    return 0 unless $block =~ /^[\r\n\t -~]*$/s;
    return 1;
}
opendir DH, "/tmp";
map {
    printf "%s\n", $_;
  } grep {
     -f "/tmp/" . $_ &&
     -r "/tmp/" . $_ &&
     testfile "/tmp/" . $_;
  } readdir DH;
```

#### Same, accepting UTF-8

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -CIO
use strict;
use utf8;

sub testfile {
    open FH, "<" . $_[0];
    my $block = " " x 16384;
    sysread FH, $block, 16384;
    close FH;
    utf8::decode $block if utf8::valid($block);
    return 0 unless $block =~ /^([\r\n\t -~]|\p{Latin})*$/s;
    return 1;
}
opendir DH, "/tmp";
map { printf "%s\n", $_ } grep { -f "/tmp/" . $_ && -r "/tmp/".
     $_ && testfile "/tmp/" . $_; } readdir DH;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(-f "filename" ) {
    #validate content if required
    #do other things
}
```

if you want to validate the *content* of file, you'll have to code that logic yourself before you do other things.

For more details read http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html.