# Checking if a directory exists in Linux using perl

Tags: linux, perl, directory

[image: subroutine: searchFileFromDirec]

I am programming in linux using perl. I am creating a program where a user can input a directory and a filename. The program will then check if the given directory exists or not and also searches the given filename in that directory. But my problem is verifying if the inputted directory is valid.

Comment: See the file test operators [-X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) and [How can I check if a file exists in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601027/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-perl)

Comment: Hi Hakon,yes I have also tried it, but what I get is, everytime I input a valid and invalid directory, it always returns true.

Comment: Ok, please post you code as inline text not as a link to an image. See [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Sorry, first timer in here :( And also, I don't know how to copy and paste in Linux

Comment: @hakon Now, I have added a function with file test operators                                                                                                                  `sub directory {`
    `my $direc = $_[0];`
    `if(-e $direc and -d $direc) {`
        `print "Is a directory\n";`
    `}else{`
        `print "Not a directory!\n";`
   ` }`
`}`

Comment: But it always returns `Not a directory` even if I have inputted a valid path

Answer (score 1):

You must have specified if the path to the directory is absolute or relative. If it is absolute, you can check with `-e` to see if it exists and with `-d` if the input given it is a directory or not.

```
if ( -e $dir and -d $dir) {
    print "\nyour folder exists";
}
```

If the path is relative, then you must create the absolute path. For that you will have to use as `$base` your drvives (you need to do that for each drive) and after, use `rel2abs` to find an absolute path for the given relative path. If the folder exists, `$abs_path` will contain the absolute path, else it's value will be undef. Bellow as an example for searching your folder with a relative path on drive `c:\`:

```
$base = 'c:\';
$abs_path = File::Spec->rel2abs( $relative_path ) ;
$abs_path = File::Spec->rel2abs( $relative_path, $base ) ;
if ( defined $abs_path ) {
    print "\n folder exists ";
}
```

For more options, see [perldoc -f -X](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#X-FILEHANDLE)

Comment: For the directory, the user input a relative path. Example: /data/edbcp/tmpwks. Then the user will have to input the filename. Example: sample.pl. I will have to append the directory and filename after then verify if the filename exists in that directory.

Comment: Edid your comment and put a valid link to "here"

Comment: Those folders are relative to a specific folder ? Or they can be anywhere on your hard drive?

Comment: These folders can be anywhere in a Linux hard drive. And I am only running the perl file in a certain folder

Comment: Now, I have added a function with file test operators                                                                                                                  `sub directory {`
    `my $direc = $_[0];`
    `if(-e $direc and -d $direc) {`
        `print "Is a directory\n";`
    `}else{`
        `print "Not a directory!\n";`
   ` }`
`}`

Comment: But it always returns `Not a directory` even if I have inputted a valid path